# What is a logarithm in the light of group theory?

Tags: group-theory, logarithms

Logarithms connect the operation of addition and the operation of multiplication.

How does group theory sheds light to this property of logarithms?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061985/what-makes-the-pairs-of-operators-and-÷-×-so-similar

Answer (score 15):

What this tells us is $(\Bbb R,\,+)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R^+,\,\times)$. (I'm using $\Bbb R^+$ as a symbol for $(0,\,\infty)$ rather than as ring-theoretic notation.) When groups are isomorphic, a specific function called an isomorphism transforms one into the other while preserving the group structure, in this case the function $\ln x$ from $\Bbb R^+$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You must write more this is not an answer

Comment: This is indeed an answer; it's probably not a good answer from the perspective of the original asker, but it's a quite good answer for those with a bit more experience.

Comment: @veronika I hope my edit addresses your concern.

Comment: For a ring $R$, I've always seen the notation $R^+$ used to denote the underlying additive group of $R$, so I was a bit confused by the expression $(\Bbb R^+,\,\times)$.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a group with binary operation $\ast$.

For $g\in G$, define $g^1 = g, \,g^2 = g \ast g, \,g^3 = g \ast g \ast g, \,\cdots$

If $a,\,b\in G$ and there is an integer $k$ such that $b^k = a$, then we say that $k$ is the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) of $a$ base $b$, and write $k = \log_b a$.

Finding discrete logarithms [may be very hard](http://wiki.c2.com/?DiscreteLogarithmProblem), which makes them useful in cryptography.

Comment: +1 this is an interesting interpretation of the OP's question, although it's probably not what the OP means. (You should use mathjax formatting on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .)

Comment: I've edited your answer to use MathJax as per @EthanBolker's suggestion. This included using `\ast` for the binary operation. If you'd prefer to edit your answer to use $\times$ instead, just use `\times` instead.